# v-if preventing bootstrap dropdown from expanding

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, vuejs2

Really weird (no mentioning frustrating) issue I've found with a v-if statement. Basically I'm trying to hide a sidebar dropdown menu depending on user permissions, thing is when I add the v-if statement, the dropdown menu stops working when the user just logs in; then, when the user refreshes the pages, everything works normally.

```
<li v-if="getUser.permissions && getUser.permissions.includes('some-permission')" >
      <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">
          <i class="fa fa-flask"></i><span v-show="isMaximized">Genetics<i class="fa arrow"></i></span>
      </a>
      <ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse">
          <li>
              <router-link to="/route1"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart"></i> <span class="nav-label">Element 1</span></router-link>
          </li>
          <li>
              <router-link to="/route2"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i> <span class="nav-label">Element 2</span></router-link>
          </li>
          <li>
              <router-link to="/route3"><i class="fa fa-list"></i> <span class="nav-label">Element 3</span></router-link>
          </li>
          <li>
              <router-link to="/route4"><i class="fa fa-leaf"></i> <span class="nav-label">Element 4</span></router-link>
          </li>
      </ul>
  </li>
```

If I remove the v-if that checks for permissions, the dropdown works just fine but if I put it back, the user needs to refresh the page for it to work properly.

Note: getUser is a vuex getter that gets the user information. The user information is fetched from the local storage in a vuex action when the main component loads, then it's saved into the application state in a variable called user, which is returned by that getter I mentioned before.

Any ideas of what might be affecting it or even a workaround to get over this?

Comment: Any errors in your console? Also, can you please define *"not working"*

Comment: Nothing, just doesn't do anything

Comment: What version of Bootstrap are you using?

Comment: I'm using bootstrap v3.3.6

Comment: You seem to be missing some fundamental Bootstrap dropdown classes like `dropdown` (on the container) and `dropdown-menu` on the menu list. Here's a working demo ~ https://jsfiddle.net/a1h0c27j/

Answer (score 0):

As I understand correctly, you need to call `$('.element').dropdown()` manually, right after `v-if` takes effect and shows element.

Personally, I'd extract this element into component and call `$('.element').dropdown()` in `mounted()` lifecycle event, but there are other ways to do it of course :)

Comment: Just tried this with no success :( 
inside my `mounted` function, I added `$('#genetics-dropdown').dropdown();` being `#genetics-dropdown` the inner `ul` (the one that's supposed to contain the dropdown menu. Am I adding it wrong?

Comment: Just to ensure that my point is valid, does `v-show` work instead of `v-if` ?

Comment: Nope, Bootstrap uses event delegation at the `document` level to detect events on `[data-toggle="dropdown"]` elements

Comment: I had the issue that I am having multiple dropdowns in the navbar. And based on some condition I am switching between them using v-if/else. But that was not working. I tried v-show and it worked perfectly.